# Developing and testing in container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I work on a project that uses very complicated environment that leads to using docker image for development and test execution. With VScode I'm able to attach IDE to docker container what's really nice but I'm looking for some better way of starting my environment, which currently looks as follows:

1. Launch docker image instance
2. Open VSCode
3. Attach VSCode to docker container (new VSCode instance is being opened)
4. Close old VSCode window
5. Open Workspace

Is there any possibility to simplify this process?
Ideally I would like to have a script that can launch VSCode attached to container and opening workspace:

```
./launchVSCode <containerId> <workspaceFile>
```

Comment: What kind of process / container are you trying to debug? Is .NET Core, Java, GO, etc?

Comment: It's just a gmock test application (C++) but the problem is that there are some code generators used during build process that are tightly bounded with particular java, python, ruby versions etc.